# why i can not solve the problem of last 2 digits multipllicatio with java 8?

Tags: java

i need help for these problem in java
Determine the last 2 digits of the multiplication of 2 given numbers.

Input: a, b integers> 0

Output: p integer> 0

Example: For a = 10 and b = 11 p = 10 (because the multiplication result = 110)
this is my work:

```
`import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.util.*;
    public class Main {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
                BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));
        String line = null;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int result = 0;
        line = in.readLine();
        a = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[1]);       
        result=a*b; 
        System.out.println(result);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

} `

Comment: please show your workings. we can help you correct your code. but we cant help you to write the entire code

Comment: please edit your question with the code

Comment: "Last 2 digits" --> think remainder operator: `%`.

Comment: thanks the good answer is result=a*b%100;

Answer (score 1):

user `in.readLine()` to read line. and remember one `readLine()` statement for per line, when file reading. if you call `readLine()` twice that means you are reading the 2nd line.

Here is my implementation .. I assumed there are two lines in your input file and always there are only integers

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            // suppose every time reads two lines
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    a = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim());
                } else {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("first integer is " + a);
            System.out.println("second integer is " + b);

            System.out.println("total value is " + a * b);
            System.out.printf("Last two digits are " + (a * b) % 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```